# how to cast interface modal to Observable {}

Tags: angular

API HTTP GET request returns the below response from server

```
{
    "results": [
    {
        "id": "206152672",
        "title": "Test",
        "restrictions": {},
        "_expandable": {
            "container": "",
            "metadata": "",
            "extensions": "",
            "operations": "",
            "children": "",
            "history": "/rest/api/content/206152672/history",
            "ancestors": "",
            "body": "",
            "version": "",
            "descendants": "",
            "space": "/rest/api/space/Test"
        },
        "_links": {
            "webui": "/display/test",
            "tinyui": "/x/4KNJD"
        }
    },
    ...
    ...
   }]
}
```

In my service file, if i do `Observable<any>` on `getNotes` function I can see the data getting displayed.

```
  getNotes(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
  }
```

If I try to caste the response to my modal, then the data is not getting displayed. When I subscribe in component it returns `undefined`

```
export interface ReleaseModal {
    title:string,
    _links: {
        webui:string
    }
    id:number
}

getNotes(): Observable<ReleaseModal[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
}
```

Please help me on how to cast my modal with the returned observable.

Note: - Response is in Object, not as Array.

Comment: Your response doesn't match your interface at all. I'm not sure how you intend to return an array of type ReleaseModal when your return values don't match that without iterating over the result and mapping out the values you need.

Comment: Your model should be exactly the same as your response, not just few of them as you defined in ReleaseModal interface. If you are not sure about any of the property whether the object contains xyz property then you can define it as optional parameter. like xyz?: string or whatever data type it may be

Comment: Look at your JSON: it's an object, with a unique property named results. It's not an array.

Comment: Yes it's an Object, so how do I cast my modal to the response ? I don't need all the details just few

Comment: You don't "cast". There's no such thing as casting. Either you return an Observable<SomeInterfaceThatActuallyMatchesTheJsonStructure>, or you use the map or pluck operator to transform the actual JSON object to an Array<ReleaseModal>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the object from the server, and what you expect (array of interfaces) don't match. What you're getting is an object `{"results": ReleaseModal[]}` not an array.

So you can either change the signature of the getNotes method to

```
getNotes(): Observable<{"results": ReleaseModal[]}>
```

Or map the results from the `get`:

```
return this.http.get<any>(this.url).map(data => data.results);
```

with rxjs map method of course.

I don't think there should be a problem, that your interface `ReleaseModal` doesn't contain all properties, which are in the response array, the only problem is, that the response doesn't contain the array directly.